# Android registration using intent service and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I am trying to create a simple app with GCM enabled. I am using AsyncTask in RegistrationActivity to get data from imput and then send them to IntentService to get token and send them to server. My question is : Is it correct way to perform such operation and if yes. How to inform AsyncTask in RegistrationActivity that registering in IntentService was succesful ?
Maybe there is more optimal  way to perform this so how in this case should I implement this :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are already using the AsyncTask then what is the need of sending data to the intent service?

Comment: Google said : ,,To obtain a token, call instanceID.getToken, providing the app server's sender ID and setting the scope to GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE. Do not call this method in the main thread; instead, use a service that extends IntentService " . AsyncTask is enough to obtain token and send everything to server ?